# Common Lisp - How to sum user input

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to take a series of user-input integers, then sum the input.  For instance, if the user enters:

```
1 <return>
2 <return>
3 <return>
<return>
```

```
6
```

Here is my code so far:

```
(defun stuff ()
  (format t "Enter a number: ")
  (let ((n (read)))
    (+ n)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example is actually more complicated than it should be since it requires multiple things (looping, reading input, and accumulating). I am going to give you two solutions, one which is the easy way and another which is how I would personally do it. First of all the easy way:

```
(defun stuff (&optional (acc 0)) ; An optional argument for keeping track of the sum.
  (if (y-or-n-p "Do you want to continue?") ; Ask if they want to continue
      (progn (format t "Enter a number: ")  ; If they say yes we need to ask them for the
             (stuff (+ acc (read))))        ; number, read it, add it to the sum, and
                                            ; continue. We need progn because we need to
                                            ; execute two pieces of code (format and stuff) in the if
      acc)) ; If they say no, then return the total sum
```

More advanced version which is how I would do it:

```
(defun stuff ()
  (loop while (y-or-n-p "Do you want to continue?") ; while they want to continue
        do  (format t "Enter a number: ")           ; print the prompt
        sum (parse-integer (read-line))))           ; read the line, parse the integer, and sum it
```

Edit: Versions of the previous which stop on a new line.

```
(defun stuff (&optional (acc 0))
  (let ((line (read-line)))
    (if (string= line "") ; If this line is the empty string
        acc               ; return the sum
        (stuff (+ acc (parse-integer line)))))) ; otherwise recur and sum the number on the line

(defun stuff ()
  (loop for line = (read-line)
        until (string= line "")
        sum (parse-integer line)))
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that [**y-or-n-p**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_y_or_n.htm) (and **yes-or-no-p**) read and write to and from [**\*query-io\***](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_debug_.htm#STquery-ioST), not **\*standard-output\***, so it may make sense to do the same when you write **"Enter a number: "** and **(read-line)**.  "The value of **\*query-io\***, called query I/O, is a bidirectional stream to be used when asking questions of the user. The question should be output to this stream, and the answer read from it."

Comment: Wow!  Thank you very very much.  I see that I'm going to really go through some more simple cases in Lisp before I can get to anything meaty.   Thank you so much!!